# How to count how many rows below a certain character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file containing this:

```
..............................
..............................
..s......................e....
..............................
..............................
..............................
```

This is my code of reading the file:

```
f = open('example.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
```

How can I read the text file and print out the count of the number of rows below a certain character, in this case `s`? Hence the output in that case would be 3 since there are 3 rows below `s`. 
 * **Assume that there is only 1 s** *

Comment: (1) find row which contains `s` (2) count rows below that don't contain `s`

Comment: What if s appears on two different lines?

Comment: Do you know how you can read the file one line at a time? Do you know how you can determine if an `s` is contained in a line?

Comment: @timgeb Assume that there is only 1 s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May like this

```py
file_contents = """
..............................
..............................
..s......................e....
..............................
..............................
..............................
"""

text = file_contents.strip()

lines = text[text.index("s"):].count('\n')
```

```py
>>> lines
3
```